# IOS maintaining a button as disabled even after log out

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios5

I have a attendance viewcontroller after my login and in the attendance viewcontroller i have in time and out time buttons to store the entry and exit time of employees.And my question is wen a employee logs in and press the intime button and logs out and when he logs in again intime button must not be visible and outtime only must be visible.please help on this...

Comment: You can manage it by core database or by server side(api).

Answer (score 0):

Use NSUserDefault and save a constant when user taps the intime button such as 0. Now if user logs in again check if value of that constant is 0 then hide the intime button.

Answer (score 0):

you may use NSUserDefault it works fine, But in case for another user login from same device conflicts the action.

so better option to use Local Database within app.

Make Sqlite table with user,intime and outtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can make UIButton inTime invisible by hiding it. For this you have to check your database where your employee entry is stored. If your employee has done inTime entry then fetch that value by using BOOL variable for it. If entry found then do BOOL variable YES and keep if-else condition for making UIButton inTime as hidden. If entry not found then do BOOL variable NO and keep if-else condition for making UIButton inTime as visible.

```html
if(BOOL Variable==YES)
{
    inTime.hidden=YES;
}
else
{
    inTime.hidden=NO;
}
```